# How do I turn off the output from tar commands on Unix?

Tags: unix, tar

I had a look at the options, but nothing seemed obvious as a manner in which to turn off the output when uncompressing a file. The below is the code I am currently using... I just need the option to switch off the output.

```
tar -zxvf tmp.tar.gz -C ~/tmp1
```

Comment: apologies i blindly copied the options from before...and didnt see that i was putting in `v`

Comment: Ha! How many of us must be passing "v" without even thinking about it. And then, after we tell tar to output a lot, we wonder why it's outputting a lot :P.

Answer (score 402, accepted):

Just drop the option `v`.

`-v` is for verbose. If you don't use it then it won't display:

```
tar -zxf tmp.tar.gz -C ~/tmp1
```

Comment: And will it show errors even in non-verbose mode?

Comment: @PhilFilippak Yes. tar sends the errors to stderr. So you'll see any error messages.

Comment: It'll also send out the extracted file's name. I couldn't turn off it either.

Comment: Just in case you want to avoid output sent to stderr and stdout, you can add `>/dev/null 2>&1`to the command shown in this answer.

Comment: @AndréGasser Indeed. If you are using bash then you can shorten it with: `&>/dev/null` (or `>&/dev/null`). e.g. `$ cmd &>/dev/null` (or `$ cmd &>file` to redirect both stderr and stdout to a file).

Comment: @ClockZHONG That didn't happen when I tried it